# Finding voltage gain and current gain using the load line in a common emmitor transistor amplifier

Tags: transistors, amplifier

So this question is really annoying me for a while so I needed some help.

I am given the output characteristics curve for a CE transistor amplifier. I also managed to draw the load line. They have given me the transistors dynamic input resistance and asked me to find the voltage gain and current gain of the amplifier given the peek of the signal given at the base. 
Any help on how to proceed would be appreciated. Thank you ^^

Edit: the question and the curve https://i.stack.imgur.com/s44h2.jpg

Comment: Why don't you show us what you got (e.g. the curves).

Comment: The stack exchange app isn't allowing me to upload images. I'll upload them to imgur in a bit ^^

Comment: @StefanWyss done ^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to have almost solved the question. I will try to give you a hint how to continue.

You know that distance QA (and QB) is 20uA. So you can see that +/- 20uA variation of Ib leads to ??? variation of Ic, which is the current gain.

You can also draw A' and B' which are the corresponding points for (only) 12uA excitation (when we consider this as a linear problem).

Comment: Ok that makes a lot of sense! Imma try that out ^^

Comment: I am guessing for change in input voltage, you use input current and the dynamic resistance?

Comment: Yes, this is the way to go!

Comment: Thanks a lot! You're the best :)